# How to change subQuery to Co-related Subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server

### Query

```
SELECT FirstName,
    LastName
FROM AdventureWorks.Person.Contact a
INNER JOIN [AdventureWorks].[HumanResources].[Employee] b
    ON a.ContactID = b.ContactID
WHERE b.EmployeeID IN (
        SELECT SalesPersonID
        FROM AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesPerson c
        WHERE c.Bonus = 5000)
```

how to change above subquery to Co-related subquery?

Comment: I believe the word you're looking for is, "correlated" and not "co-related".  additionally, here is a link explaining correlated subqueries.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638(v=SQL.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for. Just move the query into the `FROM` section and use a `JOIN` to filter the results based on the same conditions you had in the `WHERE` clause, except this time you reference the result set (RS) returned by the subquery.

```
SELECT FirstName,
    LastName
FROM AdventureWorks.Person.Contact a
INNER JOIN [AdventureWorks].[HumanResources].[Employee] b
    ON a.ContactID = b.ContactID
INNER JOIN (SELECT SalesPersonID
        FROM AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesPerson c
        WHERE c.Bonus = 5000) AS RS ON b.EmpoyeeID = RS.SalesPersonID
```

Although this is functional, it could be done much easier and faster by using a `JOIN` with the SalesPerson table directly.

```
SELECT FirstName,
    LastName
FROM AdventureWorks.Person.Contact a
INNER JOIN [AdventureWorks].[HumanResources].[Employee] b
    ON a.ContactID = b.ContactID
INNER JOIN SalesPersonID c 
    ON b.EmpoyeeID = c.SalesPersonID
    and c.bonus = 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that? This is ripe for a simple `JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
  FirstName,
  LastName
FROM AdventureWorks.Person.Contact a
INNER JOIN [AdventureWorks].[HumanResources].[Employee] b
  ON a.ContactID = b.ContactID
INNER JOIN AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesPerson c
  ON b.EmployeeID = c.SalesPersonID and c.Bonus = 5000
```

If you MUST use a correlated subquery for this, the only way I can think of doing it is:

```
SELECT 
  FirstName,
  LastName
FROM AdventureWorks.Person.Contact a
INNER JOIN [AdventureWorks].[HumanResources].[Employee] b
  ON a.ContactID = b.ContactID
WHERE 5000 IN (
    SELECT bonus
    FROM AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesPerson c
    WHERE c.SalesPersonID = b.employeeID)
```

In this case, the subquery will have to be executed for each iteration of the outer query, which is sometimes useful, but again, I don't really see the point here..

Comment: I know it can be done using Joins....But i need the same Query using corelated way... and wat are the rules and how to convert??

Comment: @HARSHITH Here are the rules for correlated subqueries: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

Comment: The `INNER JOIN` might not be an equivalent query if there are duplicates on the `SalesPerson` table. And also, the `IN` might perform better than the join

Comment: @HARSHITH Please explain why you *need* to use a correlated subquery. People here can't work on arbitrary restrictions just because

Answer (score 0):

check the comment for better understand.

```
SELECT firstname,
       lastname
FROM   
    adventureworks.person.contact a
INNER JOIN 
    [AdventureWorks].[HumanResources].[employee] b ON a.contactid = b.contactid

INNER JOIN adventureworks.sales.salesperson c ON b.employeeid = c.salespersonid 

--if the below result not give satisfy answer, then comment below line and uncomment the comment line
AND c.bonus = 5000 --this will apply and might be give the dupliate entry.
--where c.bonus = 5000 --where cluase apply after all condiotion of inner join apply
```